# How to use the pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, locust

I create a df like this:

```py
df_ts_ids = pd.read_csv('C:\\share\\pythonProject\\TS_ID.csv').head(10)
```

And I have this function:

```py
def set_ts_ids():
    ts_ids = df_ts_ids.sample()["TS_ID"].iloc[0]
    print("ts_ids : ", ts_ids)
    return ts_ids
```

It prints like this:

```
ts_ids :  53005
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  246388
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  161700
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  254692
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  312003
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  243898
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  45032
Response status code:  200
ts_ids :  45032
Response status code:  200
```

The .csv file looks like this:

```
TS_ID
53005
246388
312003
243898
161700
```

I have a Locust file looking like this using the test data:

```py
class LoadValues(FastHttpUser):
    host = server_name

    def _run_read_ts(self, series, resolution, start, end):
        ts_ids = series
        resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={ts_ids}&resolution={resolution}'
                               f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc={set_to_date()}',
                               headers={'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'}, name='/api/loadvalues')

        print("Response status code: ", resp.status_code)
        # print("Response text: ", resp.text)

    @task(1)
    def test_get_ts_1(self):
        self._run_read_ts(set_ts_ids(), 'PT15M', set_from_date(), set_to_date())
```

However I want to call the endpoint with (in this example) 10 TSids (`.head(10)`)

How can I change this line to make the `.head` value be what says how many TDids each call for each VU puts into the URL?

I guess it needs to be changed here:

```
ts_ids = df_ts_ids.sample()["TS_ID"].iloc[0]
```

?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Why are you using pandas for this operation? Why not directly read from the one-column csv?

Answer (score 1):

Forgo the need for the large `pandas` library if not running data analytics. Consider reading in the CSV, randomize values, then concatenate values with `str.join`. Below assumes your API request needs a comma-separated list of `ts_id` values.

```py
import os
from csv import DictReader
from random import shuffle
...

class LoadValues(FastHttpUser):
    host = server_name

    def _get_ts_ids(self):
        csv_file = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "share", "pythonProject", "TS_ID.csv")

        with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
           dr = DictReader(f)
           ts_ids_all = [row["TS_ID"] for row in dr]

        shuffle(ts_ids_all)               # RANDOMIZE LIST OF VALUES
        ts_ids_head = ts_ids_all[0:9]     # SELECT FIRST 10 ITEMS

        return ", ".join(ts_ids_head)     # CONCATENATE VALUES
    
    def _run_read_ts(self, series, resolution, start, end):
        ts_ids = _get_ts_ids()

        resp = self.client.get(
            f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={ts_ids}&resolution={resolution}'
            f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc={set_to_date()}',
            headers={'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'}, 
            name='/api/loadvalues' 
        )

        print("Response status code: ", resp.status_code)
        # print("Response text: ", resp.text)

    @task(1)
    def test_get_ts_1(self):
        self._run_read_ts(set_ts_ids(), 'PT15M', set_from_date(), set_to_date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your example Parfait.

The working example looks like this now:

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
import random
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from csv import DictReader
from random import shuffle
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

server_name = "https://xx.xx.com:7072"


def _get_ts_ids():
    csv_file = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "PythonScripting", "MyCode", 
"pythonProject", "TS_ID.csv")

    with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
        dr = DictReader(f)
        ts_ids_all = [row["TS_ID"] for row in dr]

    shuffle(ts_ids_all)  # RANDOMIZE LIST OF VALUES
    ts_ids_head = ts_ids_all[0:9]  # SELECT FIRST 10 ITEMS

    return ", ".join(ts_ids_head)  # CONCATENATE VALUES


def set_ts_ids():
    # ts_ids = df_ts_ids.sample()["TS_ID"].iloc[0]
    print("ts_ids : ", _get_ts_ids())
    return _get_ts_ids()


def set_from_date():
    min_tid = datetime.now()
    ny_tid = min_tid.replace(year=2021, month=1, day=1, hour=random.randint(0, 
23), minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    from_date = ny_tid.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000Z")
    # print("from_date:", from_date)
    return from_date


def set_to_date():
    min_tid = datetime.now()
    ny_tid = min_tid.replace(year=2021, month=7, day=1, hour=random.randint(0, 
23), minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    to_date = ny_tid.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00.000Z")
    # print("to_date:", to_date)
    return to_date


class LoadValues(FastHttpUser):
    host = server_name

    def _run_read_ts(self, series, resolution, start, end):
        ts_ids = series
        resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={ts_ids}&resolution= 
   {resolution}' f'&startUtc={set_from_date()}&endUtc= 
   {set_to_date()}', headers={'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'}, name='/api/loadvalues')

        print("Response status code: ", resp.status_code)
        print("Response text: ", resp.text)

    @task(1)
    def test_get_ts_1(self):
        self._run_read_ts(_get_ts_ids(), 'PT15M', set_from_date(), 
set_to_date())
```

Running the code above I get this error:

[2023-11-24 05:43:54,506] N52820/ERROR/locust.user.task: 'TS_ID'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PythonScripting\Applications\Mambaforge\envs\perftestlocust\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 343, in run
self.execute_next_task()
File "C:\PythonScripting\Applications\Mambaforge\envs\perftestlocust\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 374, in execute_next_task
self.execute_task(self._task_queue.pop(0))
File "C:\PythonScripting\Applications\Mambaforge\envs\perftestlocust\lib\site-packages\locust\user\task.py", line 495, in execute_task
task(self.user)
File "C:\PythonScripting\MyCode\pythonProject\CurrentLoadvalues.py", line 65, in test_get_ts_1
self._run_read_ts(_get_ts_ids(), 'PT15M', set_from_date(), set_to_date())
File "C:\PythonScripting\MyCode\pythonProject\CurrentLoadvalues.py", line 21, in _get_ts_ids
ts_ids_all = [row["TS_ID"] for row in dr]
File "C:\PythonScripting\MyCode\pythonProject\CurrentLoadvalues.py", line 21, in 
ts_ids_all = [row["TS_ID"] for row in dr]
KeyError: 'TS_ID'